# Displaying array from another php file on webpage

Tags: php, html, minecraft

I'm trying to create a live player counter that displays the amount of players connected to a network of Minecraft servers currently on the website of the network. For example, [Hyperbian](http://hyperbian.com/) have a player counter on the top right of the page.

I've managed to setup a .php script which queries the main server for information like ping, motd, players connected and the server name and displays it in a neat little table.

Players.php

```
<?php
//ini_set("display_errors", 1);
//ini_set("track_errors", 1);
//ini_set("html_errors", 1);
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//The following script is tested only with servers running on Minecraft 1.7.
$SERVER_IP = "142.4.210.112"; //Insert the IP of the server you want to query. 
$SERVER_PORT = "25565"; //Insert the PORT of the server you want to ping. Needed to get the favicon, motd, players online and players max. etc
$QUERY_PORT = "25565"; //Port of query.port="" in your server.properties. Needed for the playerlist! Can be the same like the port or different. Query must be enabled in your server.properties file!
$HEADS = "3D"; //"normal" / "3D"
$show_max = "unlimited"; // how much playerheads should we display? "unlimited" / "10" / "53"/ ...
$SHOW_FAVICON = "on"; //"off" / "on"
$TITLE = "My fancy Serverpage";
$TITLE_BLOCK_ONE = "General Information";
$TITLE_BLOCK_TWO = "Players";
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$ping = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.minetools.eu/ping/' . $SERVER_IP . '/' . $SERVER_PORT . ''), true);
$query = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.minetools.eu/query/' . $SERVER_IP . '/' . $QUERY_PORT . ''), true);
//Put the collected player information into an array for later use.
if(empty($ping['error'])) { 
    $version = $ping['version']['name'];
    $online = $ping['players']['online'];
    $max = $ping['players']['max'];
    $motd = $ping['description'];
    $favicon = $ping['favicon'];
}
if(empty($query['error'])) {
    $playerlist = $query['Playerlist'];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($TITLE); ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();
        });
        </script>
        <style>
        /*Custom CSS Overrides*/
        body {
            font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif !important;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1><?php echo htmlspecialchars($TITLE); ?></h1><hr>       
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
                <h3><?php echo htmlspecialchars($TITLE_BLOCK_ONE); ?></h3>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>IP</b></td>
                            <td><?php echo $SERVER_IP; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php if(empty($ping['error'])) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Version</b></td>
                            <td><?php echo $version; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if(empty($ping['error'])) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Players</b></td>
                            <td><?php echo "".$online." / ".$max."";?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Status</b></td>
                            <td><?php if(empty($ping['error'])) { echo "<i class=\"icon-ok-sign\"></i> Server is online"; } else { echo "<i class=\"icon-remove-sign\"></i> Server is offline";}?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php if(empty($ping['error'])) { ?>
                    <?php if(!empty($favicon)) { ?>
                    <?php if ($SHOW_FAVICON == "on") { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Favicon</b></td>
                            <td><img src='<?php echo $favicon; ?>' width="64px" height="64px" style="float:left;"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="span8" style="font-size:0px;">
                <h3><?php echo htmlspecialchars($TITLE_BLOCK_TWO); ?></h3>
                <?php
                if($HEADS == "3D") {
                    $url = "https://cravatar.eu/helmhead/";
                } else {
                    $url = "https://cravatar.eu/helmavatar/";
                }
                if(empty($query['error'])) {
                    if($playerlist != "null") { //is at least one player online? Then display it!
                        $shown = "0";
                        foreach ($playerlist as $player) {
                            $shown++;
                            if($shown < $show_max + 1 || $show_max == "unlimited") {
                        ?>
                                <a data-placement="top" rel="tooltip" style="display: inline-block;" title="<?php echo $player;?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo $url.$player;?>/50" size="40" width="40" height="40" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-right: 5px; border-radius: 3px; "/></a>
                    <?php   }
                        }
                        if($shown > $show_max && $show_max != "unlimited") {
                            echo '<div class="span8" style="font-size:16px; margin-left: 0px;">';
                            echo "and " . (count($playerlist) - $show_max) . " more ...";
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "<div class=\"alert\" style=\"font-size:16px;\"> There are no players online at the moment!</div>";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "<div class=\"alert\" style=\"font-size:16px;\"> Query must be enabled in your server.properties file!</div>";
                } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to get the counter to display the amount of players connected (I believe it's either $players or $playerlist) into this html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
    <title>Arylion Network</title>

        <!-- load and instantiate ScrollReveal first -->
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/scrollreveal.js/3.1.2/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>

</script>
    <script>
      window.sr = ScrollReveal();

      // Add class to <html> if ScrollReveal is supported
      if (sr.isSupported()) {
        document.documentElement.classList.add('sr');
      }

    </script>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css" />
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ie8.css" /><![endif]-->




        <script>
            window.sr = ScrollReveal();
        </script>

    </head>
    <body class="landing">
        <div id="page-wrapper">

            <!-- Header -->
                <header id="header" class="alt">
                    <h1><a href="index.html">Arylion Network</a></h1>
                    <nav id="nav">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#" class="button">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="button special">Sign Up</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </header>


            <!-- Banner -->


                <section id="banner">



                    <h2>Arylion Network</h2>
                    <p>play.arylion.net</p>
                    <?php include 'players.php';
                    echo "Join $players other players right now!";
                    ?>
                            <p>Join *insert amount of players right now* other players right now!</p>
                        <ul class="list">
                        <li><a href="#">Factions</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Skyblock</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Vote</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>

                </section>

                <script>
                    sr.reveal('.list', { duration: 2000}, { delay: 200});
                </script>

            <!-- Main --> 
                <section id="about-us">

                    <h2>About Us</h2>
                    <p>Arylion, established in ... with one mission: Provide brilliant, safe and competitive fun with a rich community. </p>


                </section>

            <!-- Footer -->
                <footer id="footer">
                    <ul class="icons">
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-twitter"><span class="label">Twitter</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-facebook"><span class="label">Facebook</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-instagram"><span class="label">Instagram</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-github"><span class="label">Github</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-dribbble"><span class="label">Dribbble</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-google-plus"><span class="label">Google+</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="copyright">
                        <li>&copy; Arylion Network All rights reserved.</li><li>Design: <a href="http://cmnatic.co.uk">CMNatic</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </footer>


        </div>

        <!-- Scripts -->
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/jquery.scrollgress.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/skel.min.js"></script>
            <script src="assets/js/util.js"></script>
            <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="assets/js/ie/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
            <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

More specifically I want the array to output to `<p>Join *insert amount of players right now* other players right now!</p>` in my html file

You can see that I've tried  to do this (But the only way I know how to hasn't worked)

Phew. That was lengthy, if you can help at all that would be so greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've updated the question, thank you :)

Comment: Questions. 1. You have a lot of html in players.php, do you want to display all that? 2. I can't spot where you declare `$players`, is that just the # of rows in `$playerlist`?

Comment: 1. Not for this question specifically, however I'm planning to make a link to players.php for each server, so players can view the status of a server, the HTML in the php file just puts all the query info into a readable neat table.

2. Looking back it I think it's # of rows in $playerlist, there's code there that does this: 'foreach ($playerlist as $player)'

Comment: I think you need to run a separate query. Is there no way to only pull the number of players? According to [this](https://api.minetools.eu/query), it is returned as part of the api call. Dont worry about including players.php. Just make a call to the api on this page. If your goal is to not write the same code twice (good idea!) then move the code into a php class. Or a function. Or at the very least, put the query code in its own file.

Comment: I'm not too sure, the API isn't very well documented and I know next to nothing about it =\ I'll have a look into it and play around! Thank you

Comment: It looks like if you, while on players.php or anywhere where you're making the api pull, you do `$players = $query['players'];` you'll get the number of players.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll use that and a mix of @YukiAsuna answer to do this.

Thank you, it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you echo directly the number of player in players.php ?

Comment: Forgive me, I'm not familiar by any means with php. Would I have to do this?

`code` <? echo <p>Join $playersother players right now!</p>?> in the HTML file

Comment: try echo 'Join '.count($playerlist).' other players right now!'; instead of echo "Join $players other players right now!";

Comment: I've put the code as you suggested like this:
`<?php include 'players.php';
                    echo 'Join '.count($playerlist).' other players right now!';
                    ?>`

However, I'm not getting any output, is this a coding issue or a query issue?

Thanks

Comment: can you put a screenshot?

Comment: [Gyazo Screenshot](https://gyazo.com/b8cd0c088eec92b7ebc3a8792ac760b3) Sure, I've created another blank html file, just to make sure it isn't my html coding not displaying anything. This html file is in the same location as index.html (so It can read players.php)

Comment: [Gyazo Screenshot of web page just in case](https://gyazo.com/0bdeff9056f7535e7c6f6edd62016ceb)

Comment: I mean what is the output in your browser when you put this code ?

Comment: The extension of your page should be .php and not .html to display php

Comment: Ah, thank you. I've saved it as index.php, now I'm getting results!
However, now it's the whole .php file, is there anyway I can just get the results for $players please? [Here's a screenshot to clear up confusion](https://gyazo.com/4953eeda40ab476e4675bff7bbc069cb)

Comment: Erase everything and keep <?php include 'players.php'; echo 'Join '.count($playerlist).' other players right now!'; ?>
Upvote the answer if it helped u